# language and country for all API routes

Tags: php, symfony, routes

I have defended a few routes under "config/routes/modul.yaml" (Symfony 4). I need for every rest route county and language.

```
# Modul route definition
sym_modul1:
    path: /{country}/{language}/modul/test1
    controller: App\Controller\ModulController::test1
    requirements:
        language: en|fr|de|es|cs|it
        country: GB|FR|DE|ES|CS|IT

sym_modul2:
    path: /{country}/{language}/modul/test2
    controller: App\Controller\ModulController::test2
    requirements:
        language: en|fr|de|es|cs|it
        country: GB|FR|DE|ES|CS|IT

sym_modul2:
    path: /{country}/{language}/modul/test3
    controller: App\Controller\ModulController::test3
    requirements:
        language: en|fr|de|es|cs|it
        country: GB|FR|DE|ES|CS|IT
```

So far so good. But I do not like the idea (later when there are many routs) to add a new country or language in each file and each route.

I have seen in the symfony demo, it possible to define the {_locale} wildcart gobal for routes. In "config/routes.yaml" it look like this

```
homepage:
    path: /{_locale}
    controller: Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\TemplateController::templateAction
    requirements:
        _locale: '%app_locales%'
    defaults:
        template: default/homepage.html.twig
        _locale: '%locale%'
```

But I think this will only work with `{_locale}` because is it `_locale` is set in the internal User Object. Is there a better way in Symfony to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you could do:

```
your_app_routing:
  resource: 'modules.yml'
  prefix: /{country}/{language}
  requirements:
    language: en|fr|de|es|cs|it
    country: GB|FR|DE|ES|CS|IT
```

Then in `modules.yml`:

```
# Modul route definition
sym_modul1:
  path: /modul/test1
  controller: App\Controller\ModulController::test1

sym_modul2:
  path: /modul/test2
  controller: App\Controller\ModulController::test2

sym_modul2:
  path: /modul/test3
  controller: App\Controller\ModulController::test3
```